# Navigation drawer menu item click no response

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I am developing an android app and am new to programming. I have extended the base drawer activity to all activity. But after I clicked the menu button of the drawer in the activities that extend drawer activity, nothing happened. Below is my code in the base drawer activity.

```
open class DrawerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    this.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    pageToGo = 1
    println("PageToGo on start activity: $pageToGo")
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    println("Back is pressed")
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
    } else {
        finishAffinity()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> return true
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_show_stat -> {
            println("I am clicked")
        }
        R.id.nav_restart_game -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_achievements -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_settings -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_about_us -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_contact_us -> {

        }
    }
    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
    return true
}

override fun setContentView(layoutResID:Int) {
    val fullLayout: DrawerLayout
    val actContent: FrameLayout
    fullLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer, null) as DrawerLayout
    actContent = fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.act_content) as FrameLayout
    layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true)
    super.setContentView(fullLayout)
}
```

Below is my drawer_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="end">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/act_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Below is my menu code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_show_stat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/nav_show_stat" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_restart_game"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/nav_restart" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_achievements"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/nav_achievements" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
</group>

<item android:title="@string/nav_our_company">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="@string/nav_about_us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="@string/nav_contact_us" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Below is my code in main activity

```
class MainActivity : DrawerActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    load()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    beginAdventure()
    main_layout.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(applicationContext) {
        override fun onSwipeLeft() {
            drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
        }
    })
}

private fun beginAdventure() {
    start_game_btn.setSafeOnClickListener {
        nextPage("ChapterOneActOneActivity", 1)
    }
}
}
```

I know I am missing something important. But I just don't know what it is. The onNavigationItemSelected seems not working because when I click on R.id.nav_show_stat, "I am clicked" never gets printed. Please kindly let me know what I should do to make the drawer buttons work in all activity. Thank you in advance.

**Edit2:** my drawer in main activity
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcZde.jpg

So when I click on Show Statistics, the "I am clicked" is never printed. How do I handle the click event to do what I want?

Comment: I don't understand the need of extending main activity with drawer activity. Usually fragments are used with drawer.

Comment: Is it unacceptable to extend drawer activity?

Comment: Can't say about unacceptable but not required in my opinion as you will have drawer activity in a single class

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i get what you mean. But can you spot the mistake I've made in my code that keep me from being able to click the menu item properly?

Comment: The nested menu tag looks problematic to me.

Comment: Problematic like how? I would kindly appreciate your help

Comment: I am not sure about this but a menu.xml file should have only one menu tag. Currently you have 2 menus in the same xml

Comment: That menu is fine. Nested `<menu>`s are submenus. The `setContentView()` override is fine, too, for what you're trying to do. In fact, your code all looks good, at first glance. Are you sure you're not just missing that log print? Have you tried something more noticeable there, like maybe a `Toast`?

Answer (score 0):

**No need** to use the below given code **separately**  :-

```
override fun setContentView(layoutResID:Int) {
    val fullLayout: DrawerLayout
    val actContent: FrameLayout
    fullLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer, null) as DrawerLayout
    actContent = fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.act_content) as FrameLayout
    layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true)
    super.setContentView(fullLayout)
}
```

***just add*** :-

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_filename);
```

i think there is no other issue in your code

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Before i try it, may i know why adding setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_filename); in the function would do the trick?

Comment: your drawer_layout contains all the views, so no need to inflate it separately.

Comment: So the reason why my click on the menu item didn't work is because i inflated it separately?

Comment: i think so. can you able to click now?

Comment: sadly no, it crashed

Comment: Last suggestion from my side:- Try to make only one class MainActivity and do all the things normally in that activity. Best Of Luck

Comment: I have added a picture above in Edit2. I think I can click it, but just not able to make it trigger the onNavigationItemSelected function...